# Unidirectional Many-to-One Mapping : Can't delete child data JPA Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, cascading-deletes

In this scenario I use *unidirectional* `@ManyToOne` relationship like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Shop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String shopName;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    private Shop shop;

    private String itemName;

}
```

```
@Repository  
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Long> {

}
```

```
@RestController
public class ShopController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;
        
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteShop")
    private void deleteShop(@RequestParam Long id) {
        shopRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

When I try to delete the shop, I get below exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "shop" violates foreign key constraint "fkedwdh6wdv6fqnyf914m5mt28i" on table "item"
  Detail: Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "item".
```

Expected:

It should delete child data item when I delete parent data shop.

Comment: ok ... so you 've both told us what error you get, and what you need to do to solve it. So, since you already know what to do, why ask us?

Comment: @Stultuske I am getting the given error and in actual i am expecting the result that when i delete row from the parent table shop then all the respected child rows which has FK of shop in Item table should be removed

Comment: that's not how it works, YOU should FIRST remove all those rows with foreign keys

Comment: using jpa we can achive this using cascade but here its not working in my case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Stultuske The `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` should take care of that, but it sounds like the database schema was created without such action.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right, in case of bidirectional mapping it works fine even it doesn't reflect in schema. seems like he don't want to add Bidirectional mapping here.